# Python and Beautiful soup, pick up All elements

Tags: python, element

I'm getting a text article from one website with help of `python` and `BeatifulSoup`. Now I have strange problem... I just wana print out the text inside multiple `p` tags which are located in div with class `dr_article`. Now the with code looking like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getArticleText(webtext):
soup = BeautifulSoup(webtext)
divTag = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"dr_article"})
for tag in divTag:
    pData = tag.find_all("p").text
    print pData
```

I'm getting following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <module>
execfile("word_rank/main.py")
  File "word_rank/main.py", line 7, in <module>
articletext.getArticleText(webtext)
  File "word_rank\articletext.py", line 7, in getArticleText
pData = tag.find_all("p").text
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'
```

But when I choose just the first element with `[0]` before `.text` I'm not getting the error and it works as supposed to. It gets first element text. To be precise I modify my code and it looks like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getArticleText(webtext):
soup = BeautifulSoup(webtext)
divTag = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"dr_article"})
for tag in divTag:
    pData = tag.find_all("p")[0].text
    print pData
```

My question is how can I get text from all element at once? What to modify so I would not get text from only one element but from all?

Comment: Did you try *looping* over the result of `.find_all('p')`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are getting all element, so the function returns the list. Try to go through it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getArticleText(webtext):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(webtext)
    divTag = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"dr_article"})
    for tag in divTag:
        for element in tag.find_all("p"):
            pData = element.text
            print pData
```

Or you can select each element separately:

```
tag.find_all("p")[0].text
tag.find_all("p")[1].text
tag.find_all("p")[..].text
tag.find_all("p")[N - 1].text
tag.find_all("p")[N].text
```

Comment: I've managed to get work myself with for loop in tag in pData and then  adding a .text to tag. But your example is shorter and I'll use that one... Thank you :)